# Excel find the sum of every 6th column in a loop

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have an excel sheet where I have already inserted blank columns through a macro but now I need to find the sum of every 6 columns and store the values in the empty column? Trying to step from 7 to 7 but it isnt working.
I need the empty columns to have the average of the last 6 columns

[image]

The code I have tried is

```
Sub sum_of_every_6th_column() 
    Dim iLastCol as Integer 
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' same as CTRL+RIGHT ARROW 
    For colx = 7 To iLastCol Step 8 '?? Unable to understand what can come here 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Which part of your code isn't working?

Comment: showing us a snipit of your code around your loop would be very helpful

Comment: Iam trying to incorporate this code but I am unable to get the values correctly?

Comment: Sub sum_of_every_6th_column()

dim iLastCol as integer

    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' same as CTRL+RIGHT ARROW 

    For colx = 7 To iLastCol Step 8
        ?? Unable to understand what can come here
    Next

End Sub

Comment: I edited you question to include the code from your comment. Are you sure this is VB.Net, it looks more like VBA (the language used in Excel macros). If it is VBA, you should edit the question to replace the vb.net tag with the vba tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Alter per your needs,

```
Sub sumCols()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
j = 0
For k = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Cells(k, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    If IsEmpty(Cells(k, i)) Then
        Cells(k, i) = j
        j = 0
    Else
        j = j + Cells(k, i)
    End If
Next i
Next k
End Sub
```